# SET NOCOUNT OFF in codeigniter to get affected rows on update

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I use following query to update data and it always return 1 using SQLSERVER

```
$query =  $this->db->update($table,$data,$where);
```

I want to on it in php side to get number of rows affected

my code in update model is

```
public function update($table,$data,$where) 
    {
       $query =  $this->db->update($table,$data,$where);
       $i = $this->db->affected_rows();
       return $i;
    }
```

and I am calling modal from

```
$this->load->model('UPDATE_model');
echo $check =  $this->UPDATE_model->update('toys',$udata3,$where);
```

Comment: Post your full code!!

Comment: $this->db->affected_rows();

Comment: Post value of `$udata3` and `$where`